# Is it possible to unpack/destructure class attributes into variables?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, argument-unpacking

I'm using P5.js, but the question is applicable to Javascript in general

In p5.js we have a class [p5.Vector](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) which is useful to manipulate vectors, since it already implements a variety of methods for vectors (addition, heading, magnitude, rotation...)

Vector components are stored in the `x` and `y` attributes, so they are intuitively easy to access

```
let myVector = createVector(1, 2);
myVector.x;  // returns 1
```

Now, some functions in P5.js don't accept vectors, but expect one parameter for x and one parameter for y

For example, drawing a [circle](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/circle):

```
circle(10, 20, 5);  // draws a circle at position (10, 20) of diameter 5
```

Now the question:

My functions usually return vectors, and sometimes I want to use this vectors to call native P5.js functions that don't accept vectors, but individual coordinates.

In this case, I use an auxiliary variable.

```
let myPosition = calculatePosition();  // calculatePosition returns a vector
circle(myPosition.x, myPosition.y, 5);
```

Is there a way that I could do that without using an auxiliary variable, and somehow unpack the x and y components so they get passed to the appropriate parameters of circle?

Comment: Does `let { x, y } = calculatePosition()` work?

Comment: but this is still creating auxiliary variables right? The idea is not to use an auxiliar variable if I will only use it to call `circle`. If circle would accept a Vector as the first parameter, I'd simply do `circle(calculatePosition(), 5);`  So my question is if somehow I can do something similar unpacking the return values of calculatePosition

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this option in the documentation, but you can overwrite this behaviour using `Symbol.iterator`

```js
p5.Vector.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  yield this.x
  yield this.y
  yield this.z
}

function setup() {
  const v = createVector(1, 2, 3)
  console.log('test', ...v)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.9.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: so how do I call `circle(x, y, d)` passing `x` and `y` from `myPosition` without an auxiliary variable? I'm not sure how can apply this answer to my problem.  Vector as a method `array()` that returns an array of the coordinates, but still I'd need to unpack this in the call to circle to avoid using an auxiliary variable

Comment: `circle(...calculatePosition().array(), 5);`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to take the values from the vector object as an array and use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when executing the function.

```js
const createVector = (x, y) => {
  return {x: x, y: y};
}

const circle = (x, y, z) => {
  console.log(('x=' + x));
  console.log(('y=' + y));
  console.log(('z=' + z));
};

circle(...Object.values(createVector(1, 2)), 3);
```